# Plotly: How to use the same colors for categories of two different plots?

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, visualization, plotly-python

I am trying to create two plots with the same colour scheme for the categories. However the plots use different colour schemas and it seems like I can't get my head around to fix this:

[image].

How can I force the plotly to use the same colors for both graphs? I’d greatly appreciate any help!

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTA97.png)

Answer (score 3):

Define a discrete color map.  In code below: `c = dict(zip(df["emotion"].unique(), px.colors.qualitative.G10))`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

# create some data
df = pd.DataFrame({"date":np.random.choice(pd.date_range("1-sep-2020","31-Dec-2020"),300),
             "emotion":np.random.choice(["positive","negative","anticipation","fear","trust"], 300)}).sort_values("date")

# map emotions to a color
c = dict(zip(df["emotion"].unique(), px.colors.qualitative.G10))

# bar chart
px.bar(
    df.groupby(["date", "emotion"], as_index=False)
    .size()
    .rename(columns={"size": "count"}),
    x="date",
    y="count",
    color="emotion",
    color_discrete_map=c
).show()

# pie chart
px.pie(
    df.groupby("emotion", as_index=False).agg(
        perc=("date", lambda s: len(s) / len(df))
    ),
    values="perc",
    names="emotion",
    color="emotion",
    color_discrete_map=c
).show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `color_discrete_map` property of `plotly.express` pie and bar chart can be used to set explicit color values for columns.

Example usage for Pie Chart:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.pie(df, values='tip', names='day', color='day',
             color_discrete_map={'Thur':'lightcyan',
                                 'Fri':'cyan',
                                 'Sat':'royalblue',
                                 'Sun':'darkblue'})
fig.show()
```

Example usage for Bar Chart:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 2007")
fig = px.bar(df, y="continent", x="pop", color="continent", orientation="h", hover_name="country",
             color_discrete_map={
                "Europe": "red",
                "Asia": "green",
                "Americas": "blue",
                "Oceania": "goldenrod",
                "Africa": "magenta"},
             title="Explicit color mapping")

fig.show()
```